# How to calculate theorectical engine max. torque from max. power and RPM?

Tags: torque, power

I'm trying to come up with a formula to estimate an engine's maximum torque (and at which RPM) given other values and some assumptions.

I'm approximating an engine's torque curve as 2 linear functions $t_1(r)$ and $t_2(r)$, with $r$ being the engine's RPM, that connects to each other at a specific RPM. $t_1(r)$ has a positive slope and $t_2(r)$ has a negative slope, making the RPM that connects the both functions the point of maximum torque, namely $r_{t_{max}}$.

From Wikipedia, I found out that the engine's power relates to the torque, approximately, through the formula: $Power = (Torque · RPM)/5252$. From this, I assumed that the power curve in the example could be written as  $p_i(r) = (t_i(r) · r)/5252$.

Given the engine's maximum power $P_{max}$ (and corresponding RPM, $r_{p_{max}})$, maximum RPM (redline) $r_{max}$ and corresponding torque at redline RPM $T_f$, is it possible to obtain a formula to calculate theoretical maximum torque $T_{max}$ (and corresponding RPM $r_{t_{max}}$)?

For example, for a car with max. power 375hp at 5500rpm, with 6500rpm redline and 175lb-ft of torque at that redline, what would be the maximum torque (and at which RPM) if one would use the said torque curve assumption?

I attempted to reach a formula through the following reasoning:

> Since $t_2(r)$ starts at the maximum torque point ($[r_{t_{max}},r_{max} ]$ range) and the maximum power is between $r_{t_{max}}$ and $r_{max}$, $r_{p_{max}}$ is within the range of $t_2(r)$.
>
> Calling $t_2(r)$ as $t(r)$:
>
> $t(r) = a·r+b$
>
> $t(r_{t_{max}}) = a·r_{t_{max}}+b = T_{max}$
>
> $t(r_{max}) = a·r_{max}+b = T_f$
>
> $ a = (T_{max} -T_f)/(r_{t_{max}} - r_{max}) $
>
> $ b = (r_{t_{max}}·T_f - r_{max}·T_{max})/(r_{t_{max}} - r_{max}) $
>
> Since $p_2(r) = t_2(r)·r/5252$ (assuming $p(r)$ as $p_2(r)$):
>
> $p(r) = a·r² + b·r$
>
> Which would be a quadratic function. Looking up at Wikipedia, the following formula gives the vertex point of a quadratic function:
>
> $x_{max} = -b/(2·a)$
>
> So the point of maximum of $p(r)$ would be:
>
> $r_{p_{max}} = - ((r_{t_{max}}·T_f - r_{max}·T_{max})/(r_{t_{max}} - >r_{max}))/(2·((T_{max} -T_f)/(r_{t_{max}} - r_{max}))) $
>
> Which I reduced to:
>
> $r_{t_{max}} = (T_{max}/T_f)·(r_{max}-2r_{p_{max}})+2r_{p_{max}}$
>
> Which, initially, looked fine, but soon I realized that this formula doesn't use the engine maximum power and appears to be only sensitive to the $(T_{max}/T_f)$ ratio.

**EDIT:**

Here is a graph with an example:

[image]

Within the ranges of $t_1(x)$ and $t_2(x)$, $y$ varies between 0 and 1, which here represents the fraction of the maximum torque (like a normalized function). $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)$ are power curves resulting from the given torque curves. If maximum RPM $r_{max}$ was at $x=4.0$ in this graph, the redline torque $T_f$ would be $y=0.5$.  Maximum power $P_{max}$ would then be $y=2.25$ at $x=3.0$ RPM ($r_{p_{max}}$). Consequently, maximum torque $T_{max}$ would be at $x=2.0$ RPM ($r_{t_{max}}$).

The real question I'm posing here is to find $T_{max}$ and $r_{t_{max}}$, given $r_{max}$, $P_{max}$, $r_{p_{max}}$ and $T_f$, and given the assumption about the linearity of the torque curve. If the problem has more than one solution - and thus a indeterminate system - then at least a formula with the relation between $T_{max}$ and $r_{t_{max}}$ would be enough.

Comment: Your problem is not well posed in that you miss one piece of information to get your answer. Your 2 data point at max power and max RPM allow you to fit a straight line, but max torque can be anywhere on that line. To know where it is, or equivalent where it crosses the other straight line, you need more information.

Comment: agree with manuel. better approach would be to obtain the actual torque curve for the engine and identify the maximum torque point, rather than trying to do curve fits in the face of missing data. You might also find it useful to review the literature dealing with engine performance curves and the relationship between torque, power, and rpm.

Comment: @user40292, that is exactly the scenario that I'm trying to deal with: in the face of missing data. Sometimes such missing data cannot be found on the Internet and trips to a dyno would be expensive.

Comment: @ManuelFortin, which data is needed? Could you shed some light?

Comment: Anything that gives you some information about where the two lines of the torque curve intersect. It could be the RPM at max torque, or two points that define the other line segment (for low RPM). Currently, you have more unknown that equations.

Comment: Also, if this is a "real world" problem, and not theoretical, I agree with @user40292 that your approach is not the best. If you look at typical torque vs RPM curve, using straight lines is only an approximation, and sometimes not a good one. See for example the second graph on this page [link](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-that-the-output-torque-of-an-engine-starts-reducing-after-reaching-a-peak-even-though-the-RPM-is-increasing) (the one with a red and a blue curves). If you want to better model this, I would use a 3rd or 4th order polynomial instead of 2 straight  lines.

Comment: If you want to have an idea of how difficult the problem is, look at [link](https://www.win.tue.nl/casa/meetings/special/ecmi08/combustion-engines.pdf) revealed by a bit of googling. Now, we are leaving the scope of this forum though and I would suggest finding an appropriate engineering forum. I am sure these people have figured out models that work under certain conditions.

Comment: @ManuelFortin, I was slightly aware of the difficulty of the problem and, as your link shows, it can be quite complicated. That is why I came up with this simpler (and thus, less accurate) version of the problem. Using 2nd, 3rd or 4th polynomials for torque curves would complicate things, so I decided to postpone them for now. Also, I updated the question to better explain the knowns and unknowns of my problem.

Comment: I would still try and see if a 3rd or 4th order polynomial would work better. It's not really more complicated. The equations are a bit uglier, but known. The maximum can be known analytically as it's a second or third degree equation (time derivative of the 3rd or 4th order polynomial), which have analytical solutions, and you only need 3 or 4  parameters to describe your system, just like in your case of two lines.

Comment: To answer your last question, you already have a and b in your solution, so this gives you the relationship between torque and RPM along the second line segment. However, the max can be anywhere on this line.

Comment: To answer you need to *assume* a certain shape of the torque curve. Then it is mathematically possible to get an answer. But IRL there are too many factors to consider to get even close.